# calculator parentheses in java in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building a calculator project in java and for parentheses are problems
My codes for parentheses for calculator project are not work right
it's work but it just put open parentheses "(" and don't close the parentheses like it ")"

```
public void parenthesesBTN(View view){

        int cursorPos = display.getSelectionStart();
        int openPar = 0;
        int closedPar = 0;
        int textLen = display.getText().length();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursorPos; i++){
            if (display.getText().toString().substring(i, i+1).equals("("));{
                openPar += 1;
            }

            if (display.getText().toString().substring(i, i+1).equals(")"));{
                closedPar += 1;
            }

        }
        if (openPar == closedPar || display.getText().toString().substring(textLen - 1, textLen).equals("(")){
            updateText("(");

        }
        else if (closedPar < openPar && display.getText().toString().substring(textLen - 1, textLen).equals(")")) {
            updateText(")");

        }
        display.setSelection(cursorPos + 1);
    }
```

Thankyou

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some info on how to debug small programs. It's a great skill to learn and will save a lot of time in the future.

Comment: I assume you're refering to the last portion of your code where the method add's _either_ a `(` or a`)` . This is because if the `if` condition is true, the `else if` will never be checked and executed. Those conditions seem wrong as well: a) add `(` if all open parentheses were closed _or the last character is an open parenthesis_? This would add `(` to a text like `(a,b,c)(`. b) add `)` if no all open parentheses have been closed _and the last character is a closing parenthesis_? This would not add `)` to a text like `(a,b`.